# внести изменения в datagrid из стороннего окна wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-datagrid

В чем суть проблемного момента : при нажатии на кнопку добавить выскакивает новое окно, в котором я выбираю из комбобоксов аргументы для новой записи в datagrid, который располагается в основном рабочем окне. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку "добавить запись" ничего не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Или же посоветуйте, как можно лучше всего реализовать этот момент. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете паттерн MVVM то ваша коллекция должна быть ObservableCollection.

А если вы не используете этот паттерн, то я советую вам ознакомиться с ним.

Вопрос не совсем полный, не понятно почему это значение должно было попасть в DataGrid.
Как вы добавляете это значение туда? Как происходит работа с диалоговым окном? Когда окно закрываете вы оттуда достаете значения для датагрид или это окно каким то образом знает о датагрид (или его прибинденой коллекции)?